# Yii2 attributeLabels - wrap part of the label in a tag

Tags: yii, yii2

Inside User model, I am using attributeLabels method to create text for the field:

```
public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'terms'            => 'I accept the Terms and Coditions'
        ];
    }
```

And in the view I am using standard **$form->field** method to show the input field:

```
<?php $form->field($model, 'terms')->checkbox() ?>
```

I need to wrap **Terms and Coditions** inside a tag with a link. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

The checkbox() method takes an options array where you can override the default label:

```
$form->field($model, 'terms')->checkbox([
    'label' => 'I accept the <a href="/tos.html" target="_blank">Terms and Conditions</a>'
]);
```

Detailed Checkbox Options are in the API Documentation at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#checkbox()-detail